# Java algorithm to split time in decreasing portions

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method in Java 7 to allocate times to a list.

For example:

if `requiredConclusionTime - now` is `1.75h` and my list size is `3`, then it should be allocated as follows:

- `item1` gets `1h`
- `item2` gets `0.5h`
- `item3` gets `0.25h`

As you can see, the allocation is declining by a factor of half.

I have the following so far:

```
private void setRequiredConclusionTimes(ApprovalForm approvalForm, Date requiredConclusionTime) {
    long currentTimeInMillies = new Date().getTime();
    long requiredConclusionTimeInMillis = requiredConclusionTime.getTime();
    long diff = requiredConclusionTimeInMillis - currentTimeInMillies;

    List<List<Evaluator>> evaluatorsList = approvalForm.getEvaluatorsList();
    for (Evaluator Evaluator : evaluatorsList.get(0)) {
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(fractionedTime); // this is incorrect and needs to be factored
        approvalForm.addRequiredConclusionTimes(cal);
    }
}
```

Each item would need a fraction of `diff`.

How do I calculate the correct `fractionedTime` for each item?

Thank you

Comment: "in Java 7" unrelated, but why?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the rules of your algorithm. Would the time before 1h be 2h? And the time before that 4h?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, I am using java 7 because it's an existing app.

Comment: What would be the output for `1h`? what for `10h`? Can't see how you would do that

Comment: @Schred, The `total time` is derived from the passed in `requiredConclusionTime` and `now`. This `total time` needs to be split up for each item in the list, i.e. each evaluator. The first evaluator gets the biggest slice, the next one gets half, the next, half of that, and so on. e.g. 1, 0.5, 0.25.

Comment: @Richard So my example was right? 6 hours would be split into 4h and 2h?

Comment: The time you need to assign to each item can be calculated with this formula: `2^(n-i) / (1+2+4+...+2^n)`. Probably there is some clever way to calculate sum of that series as well but I can't think of any atm.

Comment: @Amongalen (1+2+4+...+2^n) = 2^(n+1) - 1

Comment: @Schred, 6 hours would be split into 4h and 2h if the list size is `2`.

Comment: @Richard And what about 6 hours with a list size of 8?

Comment: @MCEmperor - 6 hours with a list size of 8 would be:  `3, 1.5, 0.75, 0.375, 0.1875, 0.09775, 0.046875, 0.0234375.`.

Comment: @Richard With this split for 6h and 8 items you end up with a sum of `5,9765625` - your numbers are incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `n`  is the size of your list, then you can determine your chunking factor `a` as follows:
`a = requiredConclusionTime/(2^n - 1)`.

Then list item `i` gets `a * 2^i` time.

See [Geometric Progression at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

Answer (score 1):

What you essentiall want is to find `x` so that

[image]

is met, where `t` is the total time and `n` is the number of splits.

The sum can be reformulated as `2^(1-n)*(2^n - 1)`, so for `x` you would get

[image]

`x` then is the value for you first item and the second item would get `x/2` and the third would get `x/(2^2)` and so on.

Knowing this you can write a method `split` as follows:

```java
private static double[] split(double t, int n) {
    double power2_1 = Math.pow(2.0, n - 1);
    double power2 = Math.pow(2.0, n);

    double factor = (t * power2_1) / (power2 - 1);

    double[] res = new double[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res[i] = factor;
        factor /= 2;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [muued's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61634036/507738), here is a simple `GeometricProgression` class which is just able to calculate your stuff, using `BigDecimal`:

```
public class GeometricProgression {

    private final int sequenceSize;

    private final BigDecimal chunkFactor;

    public GeometricProgression(BigDecimal value, int sequenceSize) {
        this.sequenceSize = sequenceSize;
        BigDecimal divisor = BigDecimal.valueOf(2)
            .pow(sequenceSize)
            .subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
        this.chunkFactor = value
            .divide(divisor, 8, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }

    public BigDecimal get(int i) {
        return this.chunkFactor.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(2).pow(i));
    }

    public void printSequence() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.sequenceSize; i++) {
            System.out.print(get(this.sequenceSize - i - 1) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GeometricProgression(new BigDecimal("1.75"), 3).printSequence();
        new GeometricProgression(BigDecimal.valueOf(6), 2).printSequence();
        new GeometricProgression(BigDecimal.valueOf(6), 8).printSequence();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `BigDecimal` though? also this would be better implemented as an `Iterator` or `Iterable` because `item_(n-1) = item_n / 2` which is performance wise better than calculating `2^i` for every `item_i`

Comment: @Ackdari The reason I used `BigDecimal` is that it allows for higher precision. And regarding implementation of `Iterable` or `Iterator` – I decided to implement this where `get(i)` had *O(1)* lookup complexity. And of course, one could easily cache common values, like *`2^i`* for each *`0 ≤ i < sequenceSize`*.